# Using two if-part in a sentence

Tags: grammar, conditionals

I've found a sentence and don't understand the grammar here. It's the first time I've seen two *if* conditions in one sentence.

Can anybody explain what it was and what grammar was used in the sentence?

Example:

> I have wondered since then – I know it's morbid, but yes, I've wondered – if she would have smoked more of it if she had known it was to be her last.

Answer (score 8):

The first *if* marks a closed interrogative (yes/no) subordinate clause, the equivalent interrogative main clause would be:

> Would she have smoked more of it if she had known it was to be her
> last?

It could be replaced by *whether*:

> I have wondered since then - I know it's morbid, but yes, I've
> wondered - **whether** she would have smoked more of it if she had
> known it was to be her last.

The second *if* simply marks the condition.

> I have wondered since then - I know it's morbid, but yes, I've
> wondered - [if [she would have smoked more of it [if [she had known it
> was to be her last]]]].